# Can we run python code without creating code file?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I want to run python code without passing its file name like **(python3 app.py)** but want to pass file content in the command line to execute the code.

```
**python3 print("hello world") \n for i in range(100):\n \t print("hello world")**
```

So I don't want to pass the file name in it but the content of the file, so there is a way to run python code in this way.

My Aim is to maintain security, I want to run a file without creating its file.py in dir so other files can't read this file.py files.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c). That way, the Python developers can improve the documentation so that future developers do not encounter the same problems you did. You would basically make the world a better place by doing that! It would also make it easier to answer the question and avoid repeating stuff you already know, or you already read and didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can use -c on the command line :

```sh
python3 -c 'print("hello"); for i in range(5): print(i); print("bye")'
```

Here I put everything on one line, but you can add newlines, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c).

Comment: Can we have same functionality with other languages too like php, JavaScript, golang?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Gix for answering, and also founded the same functionality for other languages too.

**python**
    python3 -c 'print("hello"); for i in range(5): print(i); print("bye")'

**PHP**(version 5.2)
    php -r "echo 'hi';"

**javascript**
    node -e "console.log('hello');"

**perl**
    perl -e "print 'hi';"

**ruby**
    ruby -e "puts 'hi'"